# Lateral bracket with comment in equation

Tags: align, brackets, sorting

Good morning, I'd like to know if it's possible to write a formula like this:
[image]

(here's the file I used and modified with paint:

```
\begin{align*}
(u_x) \\
\{&C_{11} Z I + C_{12} Z I + C_{13} Z I \\
&C_{21} Z I + C_{22} Z I + C_{23} Z I \\
&\dots \} + \\ 
(u_y) \\
\{&C_{11} Z I + C_{12} Z I + C_{13} Z I \\
&C_{21} Z I + C_{22} Z I + C_{23} Z I \\
&\dots \} + \\
(u_z) \\
\{&C_{11} Z I + C_{12} Z I + C_{13} Z I \\
&C_{21} Z I + C_{22} Z I + C_{23} Z I \\
&\dots \} \\
\end{align*}
```

)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd avoid rotating the labels: it just makes for hard reading. You have plenty of space, so I decided to push them a bit farther.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\quad (u_x) \\
[K_0]_x\qquad
&\left[
  \begin{aligned}
  \{    & C_{11} Z I + C_{12} Z I + C_{13} Z I \\
  {}+{} & C_{21} Z I + C_{22} Z I + C_{23} Z I \\
        & \dots \} + {}
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\\ 
&\quad (u_y) \\
[K_0]_y\qquad
&\left[
  \begin{aligned}
  \{    & C_{11} Z I + C_{12} Z I + C_{13} Z I \\
  {}+{} & C_{21} Z I + C_{22} Z I + C_{23} Z I \\
        & \dots \} + {}
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\\
&\quad (u_z) \\
[K_0]_z\qquad
&\left[
  \begin{aligned}
  \{    & C_{11} Z I + C_{12} Z I + C_{13} Z I \\
  {}+{} & C_{21} Z I + C_{22} Z I + C_{23} Z I \\
        & \dots \}
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to put two terms in two different lines on the left side?
something like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlQeY.png
?

Comment: @user122967 It seems a case of `aligned` too.